# Protractor expected returns with brackets instead of quotes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I am testing a webpage and need to use this repeater and model to make sure that the correct text was entered.

I tried doing this to get the expected text to match what I want:

```
expect(element.all(by.repeater('n in [].constructor(product.config.num_streamers) track by $index')).get(1).all(by.model('name.value')).getAttribute('value')).toEqual("testtext");
```

My issue is its showing an object with brackets instead of just text in quotes. This is my failed exception.: 
 Expected [ 'testtext' ] to equal 'testtext'.

The only reason this fails is because there are open and closing brackets with a space. Could someone help me find a solution and explain why the brackets appear?

Comment: I think this might be your problem .all(by.model('name.value')).getAttribute('value'))

I believe it's returning a ElementArrayFinder so it's not working how you expect it to. 

Previously you do .get(1) to specify the 2nd one in the array. but you don't do that the next time you use element.all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `getText()` on an **array of elements** (which is called `ElementArrayFinder` in Protractor) and, it returns a promise which resolves into **array of texts** of all the matching elements.

Since you actually need a single element, use `.element` instead of `.all`:

```
expect(element.all(by.repeater('n in [].constructor(product.config.num_streamers) track by $index')).get(1).element(by.model('name.value')).getAttribute('value')).toEqual("testtext");
```

Additional notes:

- instead of `toEqual()`, you could have also used `toContain()` matcher
- you don't need the `track by` part in the `by.repeater()` - it is automatically omitted by Protractor
- to make the code more readable, declare the element outside of the matcher - or, even better, apply the [Page Object pattern](http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects):

  ```
  var elm = element.all(by.repeater('n in [].constructor(product.config.num_streamers)')).get(1).element(by.model('name.value'));
  expect(elm.getAttribute('value')).toEqual("testtext");
  ```